# Top x rows and group by (again)

Tags: mysql, group-by

I know it's a frequent question but I just can't figure it out and the examples I found didn't helped. What I learned, the best strategy is to try to find the top and bottom values of the top range and then select the rest, but implementing is a bit tricky.

Example table:

```
id | title | group_id | votes
```

---

I'd like to get the top 3 voted rows from the table, for each group.

I'm expecting this result:

```
91 | hello1 | 1 | 10 
28 | hello2 | 1 | 9
73 | hello3 | 1 | 8 
84 | hello4 | 2 | 456
58 | hello5 | 2 | 11 
56 | hello6 | 2 | 0 
17 | hello7 | 3 | 50
78 | hello8 | 3 | 9 
99 | hello9 | 3 | 1
```

I've fond complex queries and examples, but they didn't really helped.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing - you want the top 3 voted rows (which I take to mean the top 3 rows with the most votes)?  Your expected result doesn't reflect this (if my question is accurate, 456 votes should be the first row, not the fourth).

Comment: He wants the top 3 vote-getters within each `group_id`.  The 456 is the top vote getter for `group_id` of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using variables:

```
SELECT
   id,
   title,
   group_id,
   votes
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        title,
        group_id,
        votes,
        @rn := CASE WHEN @prev = group_id THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @prev := group_id
    FROM table1, (SELECT @prev := -1, @rn := 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY group_id DESC, votes DESC
) T1
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY group_id, votes DESC
```

This is basically just the same as the following query in databases that support ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT
   id,
   title,
   group_id,
   votes
FROM (
     SELECT
        id,
        title,
        group_id,
        votes,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY votes DESC) AS rn
     FROM student
) T1
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY group_id, votes DESC
```

But since MySQL doesn't support ROW_NUMBER yet you have to simulate it, and that's what the variables are for. The two queries are otherwise identical. Try to understand the second query first, and hopefully the first should make more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I followed your instructions and finally I understand the fist query.